# Unity 2D - falling animation won't work on when falling off of an edge

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, state-machine

I'm working on a simple 2D platformer with animation and I managed to get the animation state machine to work with just one problem, the falling animation won't work when falling off of an edge, it only gets triggered after the jumping animation.

```
private void AnimationState()
    {
        if (state == State.jumping)
        {
            if (rb.velocity.y < .1f)
            {
                state = State.falling;
            }
        }
        else if (state == State.falling)
        {
            if (isGrounded == true)
            {
                state = State.idle;
            }
        }
        else if (state == State.hurt)
        {
            if (Mathf.Abs(rb.velocity.x) < .1f)
            {
                state = State.idle;
            }
        }
        else if (Mathf.Abs(rb.velocity.x) > 2f)
        {
            state = State.running;
        }
        else
        {
            state = State.idle;
        }
    }
```

Comment: surely the velocity is > 0.1f ... if falling with gravity

Comment: that statement is fine. I just cannot come up with a statement that would change the state to falling even when just falling off of the edge.

Comment: well (my head is in my own game issues :P) but surely the velocity vector shows up or down.. as a whole..you could for example compare it to "up" and get the angle, and if its >90 and <290 its downwards....in some fashion.. however, "falling" and say landing from a jump would need to be differentiated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the sprite slows down below 2f in the X direction, it will enter the idle state.  Then once in the idle state, your logic will only be able to transition into running.  If it falls of the edge, there is nothing in your code to transition it into the falling state.

You should not write the state machine like that where you specify every possible transition from each state to each other state as there are N squared permutations.  Instead, you should identify the state without caring what the current state is.

For example:

- Jumping is velocity.y > 0
- Falling is velocity.y < 0
- FallingFast is velocity.y < -0.1 (i.e. trigger your free fall animation here)
- Hurt is orthogonal (i.e. not related to movement state) and should be based on a collision
- Running is velocity.y == 0 and abs(velocity.x) > 2
- Idle is velocity.magnitude == 0

Comment: Thats exactly what I needed! Thanks alot! Also.. running animation won't be triggered when running up or downhill. Any solution there?

Comment: To determine falling, use Raycasting; shoot a Ray down and measure the distance between the sprite and the ground.  BTW, I appreciate the thanks, but can you upvote and/or accept accept the answer as well?  :)